# Sticky table column vibrates on vertical scroll

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-tables

I have a html table where the first column is fixed on scroll the column vibrates slightly but visibly (especially on mobile devises. I have no idea why that is. I think it might be to some random spaces that are not filled out:

Fixed Cell:
[image: Fixed Cell in developer tools]

Container:
[image: Container in developer tools]

I provided an example of what I would like to achieve here: https://jsfiddle.net/np42mf0q/78/

```css
.content {
  margin: 5rem;
}

.container {
  border: solid 1px green;
  border-top: none;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.fixed {
  background-color: red;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
}

.table {
  table-layout: auto;
  border-spacing: 0px;
}

.cell {
  border: 1px blue solid;
  border-left: none;
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="options">
      OPTIONS!
    </div>
    <div class="over">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="fixed cell">Fixed</th>
            <th class="cell">Not Fixed</th>
            <th class="cell">Not Fixed</th>
            <th class="cell">Not Fixed</th>
            <th class="cell">Not Fixed</th>
            <th class="cell">Not Fixed</th>
            <th class="cell">Not Fixed</th>
            <th class="cell">Not Fixed</th>
            <th class="cell">Not Fixed</th>
            <th class="cell">Not Fixed</th>
            <th class="cell">Not Fixed</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th class="fixed cell">Fixed</th>
            <th class="cell">Content...</th>
            <th class="cell">Content...</th>
            <th class="cell">Content...</th>
            <th class="cell">Content...</th>
            <th class="cell">Content...</th>
            <th class="cell">Content...</th>
            <th class="cell">Content...</th>
            <th class="cell">Content...</th>
            <th class="cell">Content...</th>
            <th class="cell">Content...</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="fixed cell">Fixed</th>
            <th class="cell">Content...</th>
            <th class="cell">Content...</th>
            <th class="cell">Content...</th>
            <th class="cell">Content...</th>
            <th class="cell">Content...</th>
            <th class="cell">Content...</th>
            <th class="cell">Content...</th>
            <th class="cell">Content...</th>
            <th class="cell">Content...</th>
            <th class="cell">Content...</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="fixed cell">Fixed</th>
            <th class="cell">Content...</th>
            <th class="cell">Content...</th>
            <th class="cell">Content...</th>
            <th class="cell">Content...</th>
            <th class="cell">Content...</th>
            <th class="cell">Content...</th>
            <th class="cell">Content...</th>
            <th class="cell">Content...</th>
            <th class="cell">Content...</th>
            <th class="cell">Content...</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="fixed cell">Fixed</th>
            <th class="cell">Content...</th>
            <th class="cell">Content...</th>
            <th class="cell">Content...</th>
            <th class="cell">Content...</th>
            <th class="cell">Content...</th>
            <th class="cell">Content...</th>
            <th class="cell">Content...</th>
            <th class="cell">Content...</th>
            <th class="cell">Content...</th>
            <th class="cell">Content...</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="fixed cell">Fixed</th>
            <th class="cell">Content...</th>
            <th class="cell">Content...</th>
            <th class="cell">Content...</th>
            <th class="cell">Content...</th>
            <th class="cell">Content...</th>
            <th class="cell">Content...</th>
            <th class="cell">Content...</th>
            <th class="cell">Content...</th>
            <th class="cell">Content...</th>
            <th class="cell">Content...</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th class="fixed cell">Fixed</th>
            <th class="cell">Content...</th>
            <th class="cell">Content...</th>
            <th class="cell">Content...</th>
            <th class="cell">Content...</th>
            <th class="cell">Content...</th>
            <th class="cell">Content...</th>
            <th class="cell">Content...</th>
            <th class="cell">Content...</th>
            <th class="cell">Content...</th>
            <th class="cell">Content...</th>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Caveat: The fixed column in my application contains images and not plain text.

Comment: add one <br/> tag after this end of table so you don't fill it's vibration on scroll

Comment: Could you please clarify a bit?

Comment: It is not jumping around for me on a mobile phone when run from here? BTW did you mean to have 'th's in the table body. Also, you do not need a class for fixed cells, you can do 'tr th:first-of-type'

Comment: See solution I included here is not jumping. This is what I try to achieve. Oh the ```th```'s should be ```td```'s of course... Please see added pictures above for a more accurate representation of the problem.

Comment: I have tried Chrome on Windows and Chrome on Android and Firefox on Windows and it does not vibrate or jump around.  BTW, unless OPTIONS has to scroll as well, the first thing I would try is moving the 'scroll-x' to 'thread tr' and 'tbody tr'.  While indirect descendent stickies should normally be okay, there is a lot of other stuff going on in formatting a table behind the scenes, and things might be being redone by the browser before it gets it "correct".

Comment: Please provide an actual minimal coded example of the problem you are trying to fix.

Comment: Please see the following Github repo for a full example: https://github.com/mxngls/admin